how to change one word's font in track_list js?
firstly i have no idea how js works i'm sorry, i'm trying to learn how to change the font of a track name in a js playlist. sorry if it is a simple or stupid question.
here is the code i have now:
let track_list = [
            
            {
                name:"title - artist",
                path:"/"
            },

it would be preferable to change one word in the name, but i don't know if i can use the replace method here, or how i would that. i tried searching online but i don't know how to incorporate the methods with the code i have, since they don't say how to do it in a track list name and i'm new to js. thank you in advance.

Here your variable track_list is an array. An array is a list of elements.
In this case, the elements are objects. In JS, an object is a variable with several key/value pairs like, in your example, name as a key and title - artist as a value, same for path and /.
So you have a list of objects. If you want to modify the value of the name key (if that's what you meant by "font") then JS lets you do that like this:
array[index]["key"] = newValue;

So applied to your example:
track_list[0]["name"] = "your new value";

0 because here you want to modify the first (and only) element in your array, and arrays indexes start at 0. Learn more here.
If you really want to replace one word in the value instead of replacing the whole value, then yes you could use the replace method:
track_list[0]["name"] = track_list[0]["name"].replace("title", "whatever you want to replace 'title' with, for example");

